# How to remove focus from `FocusNode` in a Text(Form)Field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

In a `TextFormField`, you can request focus by using `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode)`. However, how can you make sure that the same focus node has been unfocused?

For example, in my workflow, I want the `hintText` to be X initially, Y when focused, and go back to X when unfocused. But, if I use something usual like what's below, I can't go back to X.

```dart
class TextFormFieldErrorOnLabel extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final String hintTextOnFocus;

  const NewTextFormField({
    this.hintText,
    this.hintTextOnFocus,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NewTextFormFieldState createState() => _NewTextFormFieldState();
}

class _NewTextFormFieldState {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  void _requestFocus() {
    setState(() {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      onTap: _requestFocus,
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: _focusNode.hasFocus ? widget.hintTextOnFocus : widget.hintText,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a "`requestUnfocus`" method somewhere? If so, how would I call it from the `TextFormField`?

Comment: The `FocusNode` class has an `unfocus` method. Now the challenge where to call it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to unfocus  when an untappable widget is tapped
place `GestureDetector` at the top of the widget tree, on the `onTap` handler get the current FocusNode with `FocusScope.of(context)`, after that check to see if the current FocusNode has `hasPrimaryFocus`, If it doesn't, we call `unfocus()` on the current node to remove focus. If you attempt to `unfocus()` a node that currently has the primary focus, Flutter will throw an exception.
code will look like this:

```
 GestureDetector(

   onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  },
   child:...
 ),
```

credits to [this guy.](https://flutterigniter.com/dismiss-keyboard-form-lose-focus/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its the best practice but what I do is call

```dart
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(null);
```

to ensure no node is selected.

Comment: This could be a useful hack. But where do you call that? In the screen that holds the fields? But based on what? How do you call something based on a tap that's *not* on the previously focused field?

Comment: Yes, that is a good question. First I found a cleaner way of removing focus, It is ```FocusScope.clear(context)```. Next, I think you need to wrap your entire ```Scaffold``` with a GestureDetector and remove the focus on tap if that is what you want.

Comment: There are two other widgets I'm gonna investigate soon about this: `Focus` and `FocusManager`.

Comment: Worked like a charm man! The other .unfocus() was not working properly for my case! Day saver!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, what I did was I created the FocusNode object elsewhere (preferably in the parent class of the child class) and pass that as a variable, and wrap the parent widget in a GestureDetector and onTap call,

```
 onTap: (){
        focusNode.unfocus();
 }
```